# Matching book thickness of the wheel graph $W_n$

Tags: extremal-graph-theory

In the  **book embedding**  of a graph $G$ , each vertex of $G$ is placed on the spine and each edge is placed in the pages without crossing each other edge. If vertices have degree at most one in each page, the book embedding is  **matching** . The minimum number of pages in which a graph can be matching book embedded is called **matching book thickness**.  For Convenience, we denote the matching book thickness of a graph $G$ by $\mathrm{mbt}(G)$.

For the Wheel graph $W_n$ with $n$ vertices $O,1,2,3,...,n-1$, I want to know $\mathrm{mbt}(W_n)$. For the case $n$ is odd, it is not hard to know that $\mathrm{mbt}(W_n)=\Delta(W_n)=n-1.$  For the case $n$ is even, I guess $\mathrm{mbt}(W_n)=n$. For example, when $n=6$, I have tried some matching book embeddings of $W_6$ with different orderings $\omega$ of the vertices on the spine. And I always get a matching book embedding on 6-page.  For $W_4=K_4$,  $mbt(W_4)=4.$ But I was wondering whether the equality holds for any even $n$,i.e.$\mathrm{mbt}(W_n)=n$ .

I will appreciate it if someone could give any suggestions.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this is a counterexample:

Let the vertices be ordered 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 on the spine.

Page 1: 4-6, 2-1

Page 2: 6-1, 2-4

Page 3: 1-5, 2-3

Page 4: 5-3, 2-6

Page 5: 3-4, 2-5

Comment: Good job. Thanks a lot.

Comment: How do you think about  [this problem?](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/351758/matching-book-embedding-of-cartesian-products-of-graphs)